# Assign Product to OrderItem

Tags: pricebook, orderitem, product

I am trying to create an orderitem from visualforce page and I am getting an error

> Attempt to de-reference a null object

while assigning pricebookentry.priduct2Id.Here is my part of code where it is failing.

```
public class ReductionOrderProductsExtensions {

    public List<OrderItem> orderItems{get;set;}
    public List<OrderItem> orderItems2{get;set;}
    public String oId;
    public List<OrderItemWrapper> orderItemList{get;set;}
    public List<Id> oiIds = new List<Id>();
    public List<OrderItem> selectedOItems = new list<OrderItem>();
    public List<OrderItem> oItemsToInsert = new list<OrderItem>();

    public ReductionOrderProductsExtensions(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
          oId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('OrderId');
          this.orderItemList  = new List<OrderItemWrapper>();  
          getOrderItemSet();  
      }

    public void getOrderItemSet()
     {        
         Order o = [select AccountId,Id from Order where Id = :oId];
         orderItems = [select orderId,Order.AccountId,Status__c,quantity,Product_Family__c,installed_billable_as_of__c,Vendor__c,Circuit_type__c,Circuit_Speed__c,Pricebookentry.Product2.Name,ListPrice,UnitPrice,Vendor_Changed__c,Installed_Quantity__c,Revenue_Type__c,Order.Status from OrderItem 
                            where Order.AccountId =: o.AccountId and Order.Status  = 'Activated' and quantity >0];
         set<String> uniqueOItems = new set<String>();

         for(OrderItem oi:orderItems){
             if(!uniqueOItems.contains(oi.Pricebookentry.Product2.Name + oi.Vendor__c + oi.Circuit_Speed__c + oi.Circuit_Type__c)){  
                 uniqueOItems.add(oi.Pricebookentry.Product2.Name + oi.Vendor__c + oi.Circuit_Speed__c + oi.Circuit_Type__c);
                  oiIds.add(oi.Id);
              }
           }   
         orderItems2 = [select orderId,Order.AccountId,Status__c,quantity,Product_Family__c,installed_billable_as_of__c,Vendor__c,Circuit_type__c,Circuit_Speed__c,PricebookEntry.Product2Id,Pricebookentry.Product2.Name,ListPrice,UnitPrice,Vendor_Changed__c,Installed_Quantity__c,Revenue_Type__c,Order.Status,Id from OrderItem 
                            where Id in: oiIds];
         for(OrderItem oi:orderItems2){
          this.orderItemList.add(new OrderItemWrapper(oi));
         }
     }

    public class OrderItemWrapper{

        public OrderItem oitem{get;set;}

        public Boolean selected{get;set;}

        public OrderItemWrapper(OrderItem o){
            this.oitem = o;
            this.selected = false;
        }

    }

    public PageReference save(){

     try{
          selectedOItems.clear();
         for(OrderItemWrapper owrapper : orderItemList){
            if(owrapper.selected == true)
             selectedOItems.add(owrapper.oitem);
           }
        system.debug('selectedOItems ###'+selectedOItems);
         for(OrderItem oi:selectedOItems){
             system.debug('oi ###'+oi);
            OrderItem o = new OrderItem();
             system.debug('o ###'+o);
             system.debug('oi.PricebookEntry.Product2Id ###'+ oi.PricebookEntry.Product2Id);
             system.debug('o.PricebookEntry.Product2Id ###'+ o.PricebookEntry.Product2Id);
             o.PricebookEntry.Product2Id = oi.PricebookEntry.Product2Id;
             system.debug('oi.PricebookEntry.Product2Id ###'+ oi.PricebookEntry.Product2Id);
            o.Quantity = oi.Quantity;
            o.unitPrice = oi.UnitPrice;
             system.debug('oId ###'+oId);
            o.orderId = oId; 
            oItemsToInsert.add(o); 
          }
          system.debug('oItemsToInsert ###'+oItemsToInsert);

         if(oItemsToInsert.size()>0)
            insert oItemsToInsert;

           pageReference ref = ApexPages.currentPage(); 
           Id id = ref.getParameters().get('OrderId');
           ref.getParameters().clear();
           ref.getParameters().put('OrderId', id);  
           ref.setRedirect(true);
           return ref;

     }

     catch(Exception ex){

       ApexPages.addMessages(ex);

     }

     return null;

    }

    public PageReference cancel(){

      return new PageReference('/' + oId);

    }

}
```

Here is the debug log of those two lines..I see the order item is being picked but not sure how to check for active pricebookentry

[image]
How should I assign product to OrderItem ?

Comment: can you post selectedOItems query? Also check if the price book is active

Comment: @rao updated the code

Comment: If that's null, looks like you're going to want to post your controller code.

Comment: @crmprogdev  updated full controller code

Comment: what do you see from debug logs on 
             system.debug('oi.PricebookEntry.Product2Id ###'+ oi.PricebookEntry.Product2Id);

Comment: @rao updated debug logs

Comment: first off I would check if your orderitem is being picked up since you are checking for unique orderitems. If it is getting picked up I would check the pricebookentry and then check if the pricebook is active as previously mentioned

Comment: @rao I see the order item is being picked but not sure if pricebook entry is active or not.How to check

Comment: AFAIK You need to first associate the pricebook with the orderitem, insert the orderitem and then update the order item with the product related to the pricebook. when you try to access  o.PricebookEntry.Product2Id pricebook related to the Order o is null and you are trying to get the product of a null item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23430/discussion-between-rao-and-sf-dev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @[Rao](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/582/rao) for pointing me in right direction and here is my code.

```
  public class ReductionOrderProductsExtensions {

    public List<OrderItem> orderItems{get;set;}
    public List<OrderItem> orderItems2{get;set;}
    public String oId;
    public List<OrderItemWrapper> orderItemList{get;set;}
    public List<Id> oiIds = new List<Id>();
    public List<OrderItem> selectedOItems = new list<OrderItem>();
    public List<OrderItem> oItemsToInsert = new list<OrderItem>();

    public ReductionOrderProductsExtensions(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
          oId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('OrderId');
          this.orderItemList  = new List<OrderItemWrapper>();  
          getOrderItemSet();  
      }

    public void getOrderItemSet()
     {        
         Order o = [select AccountId,Id from Order where Id = :oId];
         orderItems = [select orderId,Order.AccountId,Status__c,quantity,Product_Family__c,installed_billable_as_of__c,Vendor__c,Circuit_type__c,Circuit_Speed__c,Pricebookentry.Product2.Name,ListPrice,UnitPrice,Vendor_Changed__c,Installed_Quantity__c,Revenue_Type__c,Order.Status from OrderItem 
                            where Order.AccountId =: o.AccountId and Order.Status  = 'Activated' and quantity >0];
         set<String> uniqueOItems = new set<String>();

         for(OrderItem oi:orderItems){
             if(!uniqueOItems.contains(oi.Pricebookentry.Product2.Name + oi.Vendor__c + oi.Circuit_Speed__c + oi.Circuit_Type__c)){  
                 uniqueOItems.add(oi.Pricebookentry.Product2.Name + oi.Vendor__c + oi.Circuit_Speed__c + oi.Circuit_Type__c);
                  oiIds.add(oi.Id);
              }
           }   
         orderItems2 = [select orderId,Order.AccountId,Status__c,quantity,Product_Family__c,installed_billable_as_of__c,Vendor__c,Circuit_type__c,Circuit_Speed__c,PricebookEntry.Product2Id,Pricebookentry.Product2.Name,ListPrice,UnitPrice,Vendor_Changed__c,Installed_Quantity__c,Revenue_Type__c,Order.Status,Id from OrderItem 
                            where Id in: oiIds];
         for(OrderItem oi:orderItems2){
          this.orderItemList.add(new OrderItemWrapper(oi));
         }
     }

    public class OrderItemWrapper{

        public OrderItem oitem{get;set;}

        public Boolean selected{get;set;}

        public OrderItemWrapper(OrderItem o){
            this.oitem = o;
            this.selected = false;
        }

    }

    public PageReference save(){

     try{
          selectedOItems.clear();
         for(OrderItemWrapper owrapper : orderItemList){
            if(owrapper.selected == true)
             selectedOItems.add(owrapper.oitem);
           }

         list<id> selectedProductList = new list<Id>();

         for(OrderItem oi:selectedOItems){ 
         selectedProductList.add(oi.PricebookEntry.Product2Id);
        }

        list<OrderItem>oiList =  [Select o.PricebookEntry.ProductCode, o.PricebookEntry.IsActive, o.PricebookEntry.Product2Id, o.PricebookEntry.Pricebook2Id, o.PricebookEntry.Name, o.PricebookEntry.Id, o.PricebookEntryId, o.Id From OrderItem o where o.PricebookEntry.Product2Id in:selectedProductList];

         map<id,Id> pbemap = new map<Id,Id>();
         for(OrderItem oi:oiList){
             pbemap.put(oi.id, oi.PricebookEntryId);
         } 

         for(OrderItem oi:selectedOItems){
            OrderItem o = new OrderItem();
             o.PricebookEntryId = pbemap.get(oi.Id);
            o.Quantity = oi.Quantity;
            o.unitPrice = oi.UnitPrice;
            o.orderId = oId; 
            oItemsToInsert.add(o); 
          }

         if(oItemsToInsert.size()>0)
            insert oItemsToInsert;



           pageReference ref = ApexPages.currentPage(); 
           Id id = ref.getParameters().get('OrderId');
           ref.getParameters().clear();
           ref.getParameters().put('OrderId', id);  
           ref.setRedirect(true);
           return ref;

     }

     catch(Exception ex){

       ApexPages.addMessages(ex);

     }

     return null;

    }

    public PageReference cancel(){

      return new PageReference('/' + oId);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, I dont see you are inserting PricebookEntry. before product2Id we need to have this value. [I guess this question will help you on how we can insert Orderitem.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49472/problem-with-inserting-a-new-order-item)