# I have the following trigger which is showing error "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Price Book Not Set on Order: "

Tags: community, triggercontext, before-trigger, trigger

I understand there is A required field `pricebook2id` in order OBJECT  because of that m getting error ..as m inserting order line item where do i need to use this field so that i don't get error and price book is set

```
trigger Details on Order(after insert, after update) {
    // Get all related opportunities from orders
    Set < Id > opportunityIds = new Set < Id > ();
    List < Order > orderList = new List < Order > ();
    for (Order o: Trigger.new) {
        if (o.Opportunity__c != NULL) {
            opportunityIds.add(o.Opportunity__c);
            orderList.add(o);
        }
    }

    // Query for all opportunities with their related opportunity line items
    Map < Id, Opportunity > oppsWithLineItems = new Map < Id, Opportunity > ([SELECT Id, (SELECT Description, Id, ListPrice, PriceBookEntryId, Name, OpportunityId, Product2Id, ProductCode, Quantity, TotalPrice, UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItems) from Opportunity where Id IN: opportunityIds]);

    if (opportunityIds.size() > 0) {
        // Loop through orders
        List < OrderItem > orderItemsForInsert = new List < OrderItem > ();
        for (Order o: orderList) {
            // For each order get the related opportunity and line items, loop through the line items and add a new order line item to
            the order line item list
            for each matching opportunity line item
            Opportunity oppWithLineItem = oppsWithLineItems.get(o.Opportunity__c);
            for (OpportunityLineItem oli: oppWithLineItem.OpportunityLineItems) {
                orderItemsForInsert.add(new OrderItem(Quantity = oli.Quantity, UnitPrice = oli.UnitPrice, PriceBookEntryId = oli.PriceBookEntryId, OrderId = o.Id));
            }
        }
        // If we have order line items, insert data
        if (orderItemsForInsert.size() > 0) {
            insert orderItemsForInsert;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a **before insert trigger on Order** .
- In the trigger pick the Pricebook2Id of corresponding Opportunity and assign it to Pricebook2Id field on Order.

  ```
      trigger assignPricebook on Order (before insert) {
      Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();
      Map<Id,Id> opportunitybyPBEntryMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
      for(Order o : Trigger.new){
          if(o.Opportunity__c != NULL){
             opportunityIds.add(o.Opportunity__c);
          }
      }
      for (Opportunity opp : [Select Id, Pricebook2Id from Opportunity where Id =: opportunityIds]){
          opportunitybyPBEntryMap.put(opp.Id,opp.Pricebook2Id);
      }
      for(Order o : Trigger.new){
          if(o.Opportunity__c != NULL){
             o.Pricebook2Id = opportunitybyPBEntryMap.get(o.Opportunity__c);
          }
      }}
  ```

  Ensure that API version is 28.0 and above.

Comment: That's cool ...thanks for your reply m getting error  Variable does not exist: Opportunity__c  at line 14 that means "o.Pricebook2Id = opportunitybyPBEntryMap.get(Opportunity__c);"

Comment: thanks for reply...getting error on this line 10 "Invalid field PricebookEntryId for SObject Opportunity " that is" opportunitybyPBEntryMap.put(opp.Id,opp.PricebookEntryId);"

Comment: Made edits to the code. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks Amit That worked for me..what if i want to make it work for after insert

Comment: You need to fire an explicit DML on order object, which turns out to be bit complicated. Best to keep a combination of before and after insert trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can put a make a pricebook as default. SFDC automatically picks it up while creating Orders. Incase that doesnot work, put the default pricebook2id in the before insert, before update trigger -

```
for(Order o : Trigger.new) {
//TODO assign pricebook2id 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont want to set it default ..it should have same price book of opportunity line item ..u can m inserting same opplineitme to order line item...can u just modify my code to get clarity

Comment: Check this post : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49472/problem-with-inserting-a-new-order-item